# command line does not recognise mvn(maven)

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

Here is my set up on variables path.

```
  C:\Program Files\J2EE\apache-maven-3.2.2


  %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\
  WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-  
  Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program   
  Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is %MAVEN_HOME% defined correctly?

Comment: Ι think so.. MAVEN_HOME is the title of  C:\Program Files\J2EE\apache-maven-3.2.2

Comment: Assuming that `MAVEN_HOME` is your renamed `M2_HOME`, where did you crate this variable? Is it in *system* variables or *user* variables?

Comment: I did create a new one under the system variables

Comment: Can we see value of `MAVEN_HOME`? Maybe it ends with ``\`` which would cause `%MAVEN_HOME%\bin` to be `C:\Program Files\J2EE\apache-maven-3.2.2\\bin` so `\\bin` could cause you some problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set following Environment variables there may be some other tricks but I have followed the [official](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi#Installation) way and it worked for me.

- **M2_HOME** `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.2` Upto Root Directory.
- **M2** `%M2_HOME%\bin`
- **JAVA_HOME** `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45` Upto Root Directory.
- **PATH** `%M2%`

(For Path you have to add it with existing Paths for Example: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;%M2%;`)

Just open `cmd` and write `mvn` you should Run it as an Administrator If you have lower `User Access Control`.

Comment: Thanks for that my friend. It's working now. How should i set that your answer was correct?